# Django User.check_password wouldn't pass password check

Tags: python, django, passwords, python-unittest

Trying to write a unittest which should check whether user has inputted correct password.

Using Django's native auth function `user.check_password` for this.

The problem is that `check_password` woudn't accept `user` object's own password for some reason. For example, this raises an error:

```
assert user.check_password(user.password), "Password doesn't match"
```

`user.password` returns MD5 unicode string.

Does anyone know why doesn't this pass the check and how the check can be passed?

Comment: I think you have basically answered your own question. [`check_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password) takes the raw password rather than the already hashed one. For the unit test you would have to insert the unhashed password of your testuser.

Comment: Looks like this the way to go. Works for me for this unittest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This is happening because `check_password` accepts a raw string and you are passing a hash to it.**

```
assert user.check_password(user.password)  # False because passing hash

assert user.check_password('my_password')  # True because accepts a raw string
```

`user.password` is a  hash of, and metadata about, the `password`.

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password),

> check_password(raw_password)
>    Returns True if the given raw string is
>   the correct password for the user. (This takes care of the password
>   hashing in making the comparison.)

**So, just pass the actual raw string password to `user.check_password()` and the unittest will pass.**